# Preconditioned internet connectivity

Tags: android, networking

I am trying to create an android application for mobile device management.
I want to deny the internet access of a particular 'xyz' network to smart phone users unless they have my certain android application installed on their smart phones. Only those users, who have the application installed on their device should be able to access my 'xyz' network. What should I look into to achieve this? I am not sure what to google to find an answer. :)

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly do you wish to do this but it sounds wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If this is about security, it sounds like this would only secure the network from Android users and leave a gaping security hole for any other device.  Or are you looking for an alternative to protecting WiFi with the standard clickwrap agreement before you can use the internet?  Maybe it would help if you clarify your use of the term 'network'.  The only other use I can think of is malware, so please clarify.

I suggest using standard internet security protocols for logging in - a password on a site secured with SSL, which the browser can remember.  If it's specialty content, access it directly through the app where enhanced security can be handled automatically.

Comment: Okay this is my final year project so I will explain what it is exactly. I am implementing the concept of [BYOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_your_own_device). I have an administrator who sits at the server and controls all the devices in company network. The scope of the project is right now limited to android devices. This is done to impose certain restrictions on the devices like disabling camera, sending notifications etc. So I want to make sure that unless the devices in my company have this application installed on there phones they are denied network access. Is that possible?

Comment: That seems like a precarious balance, since a rooted device may be able to fake compliance and get access.  That aside, you want to enable access to the wireless network if and only if the security app is running.  Take a look at wifi hotspots with log-in pages (free or pay).  Network access is denied unless an action is taken (in your case between the app and the server, no user action).  I don't know how the internals work, but this article may shed a bit of light on how they are used https://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-a-wireless-internet-hotspot-at-home-in-10-minutes-for-free/